# Is there a possibility in ROS to check that the other machine messages publish in the topic without direct transfer of messages between the machines?

Tags: ros, messages, ros-kinetic, multiple-machines

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Is there a possibility in ROS to check that in the other machine messages publish in the topic without direct transfer of messages between the machines?

I would like to transfer between machines only the information that the message was published in topic without transferring the exact things in it.

I tried to use the «Message Event», but according to traffic of the router, the messages were transmitted completely.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/281165/is-there-a-possibility-in-ros-to-check-that-in-the-other-machine-messages-publish-in-the-topic-without-direct-transfer-of-messages-between-the-machines?/) by [baltic](https://answers.ros.org/users/30706/baltic/) on ROS Answers with karma: 35 on 2018-01-29

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-01-29**:
Do you need an event *per message*, or are aggregate statistics enough?

**Comment by [baltic](https://answers.ros.org/users/30706/baltic/) on 2018-02-04**:
Statistics is enough, but if it possible to receive an event per message, it would be better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you want statistics on topic rate for monitoring and alerting, you may want to set up the ROS [diagnostics framework](http://wiki.ros.org/diagnostics) and use the [DiagnosedPublisher class](http://docs.ros.org/lunar/api/diagnostic_updater/html/classdiagnostic__updater_1_1DiagnosedPublisher.html) from the diagnostic_updater package.

If you want to monitor aggregate statistics on the entire topic graph and you don't need monitoring or alerting, you may want to enable topic_statistics and use rqt_graph to measure the publish rate: http://wiki.ros.org/rqt_graph#Topic_statistics (note that this only works for topics that are actually published and subscribed, because it's per-link and not per-publisher)

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2018-01-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [baltic](https://answers.ros.org/users/30706/baltic/) on 2018-02-04**:
Thanks, ros statistics is what I wanted